# Variables inside my created function are not being saved in the enviroment

Tags: r

I want to read in a new york times article and the parse the article into two lists, `paragraphs` (which is a nested list with regular paragraph structure) and `paragraphs_separated_by_word` where each word is separated by a space, same nested list structure as `paragraphs`. The code works when I don't run it as a function, the two variables are created and all is well, but not when I have it as function. I want to make it a function so that I can do proper testing on it.

```
library('rvest') 

url <- 'https://www.nytimes.com/2020/07/15/science/hybrid-sturgeon-paddlefish.html'

readNYTLink <- function(url){
  NYTwebpage <- read_html(url)
  NYTwebpage %>%
    html_nodes(".css-53u6y8 p") %>%
    html_text() -> paragraphs
  NYTwebpage %>%
    html_nodes(".css-53u6y8 p") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_split(' ') -> paragraphs_separated_by_word
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Right, that's how functions work in R (or in functional languages, generally) - they do things in their own function environment without messing up the your main environment. Your function should `return()` anything you want saved, perhaps `return(list(paragraphs, paragraphs_separated_by_word))` in your case, and when you call the function you assign the result, e.g., `sturgeon_text <- readNYTLink(url)`.

Comment: Read up on how environments work in R. Your variables do not get passed to the global environment and are destroyed after function execution.

Comment: If you have `x <- 1:10`, and you run `mean(x)`, it doesn't create a new variable named `mean`, if you want to keep the result around you assign it `my_mean <- mean(x)`. Your function should work just the same way.

Comment: Take these comments to heart. There actually is a hackish way to move the variables into the global environment (use `<<-` rather than `<-`) which you might see in your search for an answer. If so -- avoid the temptation to use it. Many (most?) experienced R programmers regard `<<-` as a design flaw in R, one which is inconsistent with good programming practices.

Comment: @JohnColeman `<<-` is not a design flaw. It has valid use cases. The issue is that it gets misused for function side effects.

Comment: @Roland Good point.

Comment: You could also export objects from your function's environment to the global environment.

Comment: Thank you for all of the comments, I've been using R for a couple months now but am still new to program design and writing functions. I appreciate all the help